# How to stack rows of data frame

Tags: r

I'm having trouble stacking rows in a data.frame into one row. My data looks something like this:

```
v1       v2      v3      index     
var1     ad      b1      1    
var2     sa      b2      2     
var3     4       b3      3     
var1     5       b4      1     
var2     6       b5      2    
var3     2       b6      3
.        .       .       . 
.        .       .       . 
.        .       .       .
```

I'm trying to transpose the data so v1 becomes my colnames and they are also stacked. I'm familiar with the native transpose command `t()` and assigning the colnames as the first row. However, I'm not sure how to stack the rows. I did break up each group of rows (in three's) transposed and then binded them in a loop, but it's very slow, as my data set is 1gb.

```
var1   var2  var3
ad     sa     4
b1     b2     b3
5      6      2
b4     b5     b6
.      .      .
.      .      .
.      .      .
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should be able to use `tidyr::spread` or `reshape2::dcast` (search for something like "data long to wide"), but you will probably need to first create an `id` column that identifies which rows go together. Maybe it's as simple as `0:(nrow(your_data) - 1) %/% 3` if your rows are sorted in the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `recast` function from `reshape2` is well suited for this. But before you use that, you need to transform you `index`-column in a better grouping variable:

```
# transform 'index' into a grouping variable
dat$index <- cumsum(c(0, head(dat$index, -1) > tail(dat$index, -1)))

# reshape into the new format
library(reshape2)
recast(dat, variable + index ~ v1, id.var = c('v1','index'))[,3:5]
```

now your data looks like this:

```
  var1 var2 var3
1   ad   sa    4
2    5    6    2
3   b1   b2   b3
4   b4   b5   b6
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about it wrong, but I can still sort after recasting and it'll come out exactly the same.